# How to compile C program in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, compilation, vscode-debugger

I installed VSC and wrote this program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    printf("Hello world!");
}
```

Then I installed a C/C++ debugger and I saved the file on the desktop as "hello.c" and magically the syntax became higlighted.

Now I would like to run the program, but can't find a way.
There's no "run" or "build" option anywhere, and if I start the debugging and choose the debugger then I got a new tab named "settings.json" with a couple of brackets waiting for me to write something.

Also in the left I can read that I "have not yet opened a folder". What does it even mean?

And the line `#include <stdio.h>` is underlined in red, like there's something wrong going on, maybe I have to download the library?

I would do anything to see the output of the program, please help me.

Comment: Use  [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) after having read its documentation (e.g. with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). Consider installing [Debian](https://debian.org/) on your laptop (it provides both `gcc` and the [`gdb` debugger](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/), and also [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/)...). Read of course [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) and this [C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch thank you for the suggestions, I will get informed about GCC and Debian

Answer (score 0):

have you added c/c++ and code runner extensions?

Comment: I installed the extensionshowed in this page https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp I thought it was a debugger. So adding even *code runner* I would be good to go?

Comment: You'll might need MinGW-x64 or similar. follow the instructions in that page...

Answer (score 0):

Add Code Runner and C/C++ extension in VS CODE

You can refer following link to see How to Write And Run C and C++ Code in VS CODE
[LINK](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-write-and-run-c-cpp-code-on-visual-studio-code/)